# Form is not navigating to another page

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

```
<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >
    <p>
        <input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;" />
    </p>
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myClickHandler(){
         if(validation()){
                    showConfirm();
         }
    }
</script>

<?php
    session_start();

    $outputDetails = "";
    $outputDetails .= "<table id='sessionDetails' border='1'>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Number of Sessions:</th> 
                                <th>{$_POST['sessionNum']}</th>
                            </tr>";
    $outputDetails .= "</table>";
    echo $outputDetails;
?>
```

Above is the code for my form. What I am trying to do is that if the user submits the form, then it will go back to its own page. But if the "SessionNum" equals '1', then instead of posting the form to itself, it should post the form or in other words navigate to the "session_marks.php' page but it is not idng this, if sessionNum equals 1 then it still submits form or navigate back to its own page, what am I doing wrong?

Also lets say it displays a number for the sessionNum and then I submit the form and it submits the form back to itself, the number disappears, how do I keep the number displayed when submitting the form to itself?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use `htmlentities()` on a $_SERVER variable?

Comment: I don't know this is just an example I saw from the web when using PHP_SELF

Comment: Could you show us the end result of all this? the actual HTML that comes out?

Comment: Please include your javascript function references. `onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;` and `onsubmit="return validateForm(this);"` .. The submit button will execute the myClickHandler() function and then stop due to `return false;` if you don't actually have those functions in your script it's not going to do anything ... so we'd have to see those javascript functions, too.

Comment: Give me 5 mins to show you what the HTML looks like.

Comment: @Blake I included myClickHandler() function but I do not have the onsubmit... function, do I actually need this because I don't think I have this in another form I am making?

Comment: Hi, I managed to get the html up, please click on this link [link](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session2.php) then type in the number 1 in the textbox and click on the prepare answers button. When you go on the next page, click on the submit details button and you see that the page doesn't naviagte to a new page and it is giving me a notice

Comment: "do I actually need this..." If you're not sure you actually need it, why would I know? Cut out anything you don't use. Your form is using functions that you don't know if they exist or not. I got this error when I went to your link: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '}' in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php on line 70` So we're going to need the source code of that file (Remove any username / password / sensitive information references). It seems like there's syntax issues in php more than your form oddities.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the conditional logic to change the target of the form post?  All I see in the `form` tag is this:

```
action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"
```

This will always set the `form`'s `action` to be the current PHP file, not any other PHP file.  If you want to conditionally post to a different file, you'll need to add conditional logic in there.  Something like this (though there may be better ways to do it, keep in mind that I'm *very* out of practice with PHP):

```
action="<?php $_POST['sessionNum'] == 1 ? echo 'session_marks.php' : echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"
```

As for the number disappearing, I don't see any form element with the name `sessionNum`.  If there isn't such a form element, then there will be nothing in `$_POST['sessionNum']`, so the number will "disappear" because there's no value to be displayed.

Comment: Hi, The sessionNum is from a previous page, the user enters in a number in a textbox in the previous page and then in the current page it will display the number entered in the previous page.

Comment: @user1292857: That will work for the initial post to the current page.  But once they re-post to the current page, if there's no `sessionNum` in the form being posted, there will be no value to display.

Comment: Is there a way this can be solved, or am I going about this the worng way when it somes to submitting the form to itself?

Comment: @user1292857: I'm not sure what you're trying to solve.  If you need to track the `sessionNum` value then you have a couple of options.  You can store it in session state (something like `$_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum']`) and then refer to it from the session state instead of the form post.  Or you could write it to the form as a hidden field so it will post back again.  Something like: `<input type="hidden" name="sessionNum" value="<?php echo $_POST['sessionNum']; ?>" />

Comment: Hi, I managed to get the html up, please click on this link link then type in the number 1 in the textbox and click on the prepare answers button. When you go on the next page, click on the submit details button and you see that the page doesn't naviagte to a new page and it is giving me a notice. If you read my question again and look at html then I think you will understand.

Comment: @user1292857: There's no link.  But keep in mind also that I can't see your server-side code in a live demonstration.  So far the issues I've pointed out are in server-side code.

Comment: Hi,sorry I have included the same comment with the link in the comments at the top so you can see what it looks like but I will do what you said and replace $_POST['sessionNum'] with $_SESSION['sessionNum'].

Comment: @user1292857: Well, keep in mind that one is not a drop-in replacement for the other.  You should take some time to learn about state tracking in a web application.  Session is useful for server-side state tracking, forms and query strings are useful for client-visible state tracking (and is often much more RESTful).  The two have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

If the above is your actual code, session_start(); has to be placed before ANY other output (html, php's echo, print etc...)

Comment: I've put session_start() at start but still doing same thing, when number is '1' it does not navigate to another page, it navigates to same page with notice